# Simple differential equations problems

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have an ODE.
$$
yy^{\prime\prime}-2(y^{\prime})^2+2y^{\prime}=0.
$$
My lecturer got the answer
$$
y=C,
$$
where $C$ is an arbitrary constant, or
$$
y=\frac{1}{\sqrt{C_1}}\tan(\sqrt{C_1}x+C_2),
$$
where $C_1,C_2$ are arbitrary constants, $C_1>0$.

But I think the solution may differ due to the sign of $C_1$. Let $y^{\prime}=v$, then
$$
y^{\prime\prime}=\frac{dv}{dx}=\frac{dv}{dy}\frac{dy}{dx}=v\frac{dv}{dy}. 
$$
So this ODE becomes 
$$
vy\frac{dv}{dy}-2v^2+2v=0.
$$
Case 1: $v=0$, then $y=C$, $C$ is an arbitrary constant;

Case 2: if $v\ne0$, then separate variables, giving
$$
\frac{1}{v-1}dv=\frac{2}{y}dy. 
$$
Integrate both sides, we have 
$$
\int\frac{1}{v-1}\mathrm{d}v=\int\frac{2}{y}\mathrm{d}y, 
$$
i.e.,
$$
\ln|v-1|=\ln y^2+\ln|K|,
$$
where $K$ is a non-zero constant. So we have
$$
e^{\ln|v-1|}=e^{\ln|K|}e^{\ln{y^2}}, 
$$
and finally 
$$
|v-1|=|K|y^2.
$$
Therefore,
$$
v-1=\pm|K|y^2.
$$
Let $C_1=\pm|K|$, then 
$$
v=C_1y^2+1,
$$
where $C_1$ is a non-zero constant. Separate variables again, we get
$$
\int\frac{1}{C_1y^2+1}\mathrm{d}y=\int \mathrm{d}x. 
$$ 
Here is the problem: if $C_1<0$, we cannot use the integral
$$
\int\frac{1}{x^2+a^2}\mathrm{d}x=\frac{1}{a}\arctan\frac{x}{a}+C, 
$$
where $C$ is an arbitrary constant, instead, we need to use 
$$
\int\frac{1}{ax^2+b}\mathrm{d}x=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{-ab}}\ln\left|\frac{\sqrt{a}x-\sqrt{-b}}{\sqrt{a}x+\sqrt{-b}}\right|+C,\ a>0\ \text{and}\ b<0
$$
to solve the ODE. Am I wrong or was my lecturer wrong? I always got confused with these constants in first order ODE's. Thank you.

Comment: First of all: did you check if your solutions are actually solutions? If they are, your instructure forgot them.

Comment: @Siminore Oh yeah I forgot I could check the solution! Thank you so much~ :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, and perhaps your lecturer too if he allows for complex arguments in the tangens and arc tangens functions. Then one can use 
$$
\tanh(ix)=i\tan(x)=y,
$$
and thus 
$$
\arctan(iy)=-\arctan(\tan(x))=-x=i\operatorname{Artanh}(y)
$$
The logarithm in your formula is just a different expession for $\operatorname{Artanh}$, since
$$
y=\tanh(x)=\frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{e^x+e^{-x}}=\frac{e^{2x}-1}{e^{2x}+1}
$$
is equivalent to
$$
e^{2x}=\frac{1+y}{1-y}\iff x=\frac12\ln\left(\frac{1+y}{1-y}\right).
$$

Comment: Ah yes that's it.. I just assume everything's in the real field.. Thanks bro.